# mysql float data field not accepting every float number

Tags: mysql

I have a float data field :

```
`total` float(20,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

I want to insert a float number like : "815032.68" but it's not accepted and the number is rounded to 815032.69. why?

Comment: Please post more code (specifically an insert of 815032.68 that results in a table value of 815032.69)

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin to insert this number.

Comment: Please try inserting the value with raw SQL to rule out any defects in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You can understand here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: use double instead of float I think memory problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *fixed-point* data type

```
`total` DECIMAL(20,2) unsigned NOT NULL
```

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store **exact** numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

[MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

*Floating-point* data types can only store [approximate numbers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html).

Answer (score 1):

Floats are 32 bit numbers stored as mantissa and exponents,the maximum value a FLOAT can have is +8388608*10^127 and the minimum is -8388608*10^127. This means only 7 significant digits, and your FLOAT definition used 20.Use double data type.